# Excel Form: VBA Code to copy a cell when a check box is selected

Tags: excel, checkbox, activex, vba

I am new to Excel forms and was wondering if someone could help with a simple code for a program I am trying to create for work. Basically, to make my job easier!

What I'm looking for is code that when a specific checkbox is selected and I hit a copy button, it copies a specific cell. I will have multiple checkboxes but just one copy button. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add code snippets of what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

this assumes your copy button is named CopyButton 
it will copy cell A1 if a check box named CheckBox1 is checked
A2 if CheckBox2 is checked etc you can change the cell references below
you didn't really specify what to do with the copied data so it just copies it and does nothing

```
Public Sub CopyButton_Click()

    if(CheckBox1.Value = true) then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").copy
    end if

    if(CheckBox2.Value = true) then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A2").copy
    end if

    'copy the chunk above for more check boxes

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply. I was actually embarrassed to add what I tried.  I was orig. able to get the copy button to work, but not the checkboxes. This is my first try at this. But the above works Perfect!!! Thank you so much! There is one other thing I forgot to mention. It there a way to add code so only one checkbox can be checked at a time?  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "so only one checkbox can be checked at a time" can you make it clearer please?

Comment: Sorry about that! Lets see....So, I have a copy button  with 3 checkboxes (A1, A2 & A3), depending on what check box is checked when I hit the copy button it will copy a specific cell number.  However, I only want one check box to be able to be check at one time.  So, if I push "A1"  then select "A2" it will cause "A1" to uncheck. Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Ah yes I understand now.. You could add some code so that when you change the value of a checkbox the others change accordingly however a much neater way to do it would be to use option buttons. They function similarly to check boxes however by default you can only select one at a time, should be perfect for this. You will need to replace you check boxes with option buttons and change the code from CheckBox1.Value to OptionButton1.Value etc but that should do it, link below for more info on option buttons :)

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-buttons.html